# PostgreSQL user's privileges listing for a particular database

Tags: postgresql, yii, privileges, psql

i have a user created under login roles in pgAdmin. user's name is '**myApp**'.

here is the pgsql syntax to create it.

```
CREATE ROLE myApp LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md58e0b379fc6e92422518682611bcf2d42'
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
```

all these days i had my application developed by yii framework to connect to database with super user in my end. which is.. user '**postgres**'

but after doing a release recently i started getting an error as below

[image]

i found its because of i have set permission to the **myApp** user role for newly created table but have missed to do the same for sequence so i wrote the below script to resolve..

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE css_ataps_client_outgoing_call_dates_id_seq TO myAppAdmin;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLE css_ataps_client_outgoing_call_dates_id_seq TO myApp;
```

now i need to enable my application to connect to database using the same login as my production application which is **myApp** but not **postgres**.

but unfortunately it doesn't work unless i use **postgres** user. The error i got when trying to connect with **myApp** user is nothing. not even recorded in logs. so i can confirm that login details are same and its working and the issue could be the user **myApp** doesnt have read / write access to any single table. **so i want to check for which table in database it doesnt have permission or vice versa.**

please tell me a way to find this out. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do. Try and let me know.

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE <ur database name> TO myApp; <- not this
```

TRY THIS QUERY..!

```
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myApp;
```

Comment: GRANT ALL ON DATABASE myDatabaseName TO myApp;